# Phonegap Full Scren iPad application

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, cordova, phonegap-plugins

How would I go about removing the bar at the top with the following contents:

1. iPad
2. Signal
3. Time
4. Extras
5. Battery

with a Phonegap application?

In other words, I want a full screen application with the full 1024x768 at my disposal.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you make any progress with any of the answers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process is the same as a standard iOS app, the AppDelegate just launches et HTML page in a UIWebView. So you can call the setStatusBarHidden method in the AppDelegate.m like so :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
...
...
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Using Phonegap you can edit the Info.plist (Supporting Files -> [appname]-Info.plist)

In xCode, right click at the bottom of the plist document and choose "Add Row", then select "Status bar is initially hidden" and change the boolean value to YES.

Answer (score 0):

I think the method you are looking for is setStatusBarHidden:withAnimation: on UIApplication. From the documentation:

setStatusBarHidden:withAnimation:
Hides or shows the status bar, optionally animating the transition.

- (void)setStatusBarHidden:(BOOL)hidden withAnimation:(UIStatusBarAnimation)animation
  Parameters
  hidden
  YES to hide the status bar, NO to show the status bar.
  animation
  A constant that indicates whether there should be an animation and, if one is requested, whether it should fade the status bar in or out or whether it should slide the status bar in or out.
  Discussion
  See the descriptions of the constants of the UIStatusBarAnimation type for more information.

Availability
Available in iOS 3.2 and later.

Comment: What is the correct way to do this with PhoneGap, though? I am not sure the startup process is the same with PhoneGap and a standard iOS app...